# How to exit when loop when the min of the sizes of two tables is reached

Tags: ruby

I am doing some data migration, comparing tables between a legacy and a new database. I have a loop that raises exceptions when two arrays do not have the same size.

```
array1.zip(array2).each do |ar1, ar2|
  # some code here
end
```

I want to know how to exit the loop when we reach the same size of the two arrays.

Comment: Why not just `raise 'error' if array1.length != array2.length`?

Comment: each array represents a rows of a DB table, and because of the DB migration code, I want to test if data is the same, so I will chose to stop the iteration when one table reach its size even if the other still have more rows.

Comment: Are these two arrays, or two arrays of arrays? Are you looking for when `array1` and `array2` are different lengths or when `array1[n]` and `array2[n]` don't match length?

Comment: @tadman, it is just what the asker is already using. *"I have a loop that rise exceptions (...)"*

Comment: @Robert Since they already have that code, why repeat it?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop breaks when reaches the last element of the first array zipped.

```
array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
array2 = ['x', 'y', 'z']

array1.zip(array2).each do |ar1, ar2|
   puts "#{ar1} -- #{ar2}"
end

puts "-"*10

array2.zip(array1).each do |ar2, ar1|
   puts "#{ar1} -- #{ar2}"
end
```

You could swap the variables if the first array is bigger:

```
array1, array2 = array2, array1 if array1.size > array2.size
array1.zip(array2).each do |ar1, ar2|
   puts "#{ar1} -- #{ar2}"
end
```

If you just want to check if data are the same and don't want keep track of data origin.

Comment: Thank you iGian, but we don't know in advance which array is bigger, that's why I choose to find the min .

Comment: iGian, swapping is a smart idea.

Comment: `arrays = [array1, array2].sort_by(&:length)` is a little easier to follow, plus scales up to *N* arrays. Then `arrays.transpose` instead of `.zip`.

Comment: @tadman's comment, as it concerns the construction of `arrays`, is also non-destructive, whereas parallel assignment mutates `array1` and `array2`, which may not be wanted. tadman: don't you want the smaller array first (e.g., tack `reverse` onto the end)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland This question would benefit by having a series of tests any solution should pass. Too many people fail to post their specifications and leave us guessing as to what they really want.

Comment: @tadman, forget my mention of `reverse`. I wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 2):

```
 [array1.size, array1.size].min.each do |i|
   # code here referencing array1[i] and array2[i]
 end
```

Comment: It is an alternative to using `zip`. Suppose  `array1 =  [1,2,3]` and `array2 =  [4,5]` and you wish to print `5` (`1+4`) and then `7` (`2+5`). Using `zip` you might write, `n = [array1.size, array2.size].min #=> 2`, then `arr = array1[0,n].zip(array2[0,n]) #=> [[1,4], [2,5]]` (as `array1[0,2] #=> [1,2]` and `array2[0,2] #=> [2,5]`). Then `arr.each { |a,b| puts a+b }` prints `5` and then `7`.  Here I suggest `n.times { |i| puts array1[i]+array2[i] }` which also prints `5` and then `7`.

Answer (score 1):

Given arrays:

```
a = %w[ 1 2 3 10 ]
b = %w[ 1 4 5 1 ]
c = %w[ 5 4 3 ]
```

If you want to compare two arrays for length:

```
a.length == b.length
# => true
a.length == c.length
# => false
```

If you want to compare that the elements *in* the arrays are of the same length *and* that the arrays are the same length:

```
def equal_size_elements(a, b)
  return false unless a.length == b.length

  a.zip(b).all? do |_a, _b|
    _a.length == _b.length
  end
end
```

Where that checks if all of the elements have different lengths because if they all match then it's good, otherwise not good. That method will halt iterating as soon as it finds a mismatch because at that point they can't all pass.

Comment: I tested your def puts equal_size_elements(a, b), it returned false !!!

Comment: That's because `a[4]` and `b[4]` have different lengths, 2 vs 1 in this case, which is not a match.

Comment: the index goes from 0 to 3, where a[4] come from ?

Comment: From my not zero-indexing, my mistake. That should be `a[3]` and `b[3]`, but the point is that `"10"` and `"1"` have different lengths ergo the arrays are not "equal size" by this definition.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, maybe there is better one than mine, I am just a beginner in ruby :

```
  j = 0
  array1.zip(array2).each do |ar1, ar2|
   j += 1
   break if [array1.size,array2.size].min == j
   ....
   end
```

Comment: where are you using ar1 and ar2?

Comment: inside the loop, I have hc = HashCompare.new(ar1, ar2)

Comment: both the question and the answer are completely unclear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit better than your solution:

```
array1.zip(array2).each_with_index do |zipped, index| 
    break if index == [array1.size, array2.size].min
    puts zipped.first
    puts zipped.last
    puts
end
```

Comment: Cassiano, yes this is better than mine, I am the poor student.